# TFS How to merge a changeset from one branch to another in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfvc

How do I merge a changeset from one branch to another?

I've tried to create a new changeset, fill in an existing changeset and change the item.path in the change I want to merge. Tried everything I can think of. I keep getting an exception "The combination of parameters is either not valid or not complete." Which tells me nothing really about what's missing.

```
            int changeset_id = 18767;
            string collectionUri = "My TFS Server";
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssCredentials());
            TfvcHttpClient client = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();

            var original_changeset = client.GetChangesetAsync(changeset_id, null, true).Result;
            var changes = client.GetChangesetChangesAsync(changeset_id).Result;
            var workitems = client.GetChangesetWorkItemsAsync(changeset_id).Result;

            string oldPath = changes[0].Item.Path;
            changes[0].ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Merge;
            changes[0].Item.Path = destination;
            changes[0].Item.ChangesetVersion = changeset_id;
            changes[0].Item.ContentMetadata = new FileContentMetadata()
            {
                Encoding = Encoding.UTF8.WindowsCodePage,
                ContentType = "text/plain",
            };
            original_changeset.Changes = changes;
            original_changeset.WorkItems = workitems;
            var stream = client.GetItemContentAsync(oldPath).Result;


            // convert stream to string
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            changes[0].Item.Content = text;

            TfvcChangesetRef changesetRef = client.CreateChangesetAsync(original_changeset).Result;
```

Here is some test code. Please don't slam me on format. I'm just throwing code at the problem at this point. It's amazing how little MS documents their stuff these days.

Comment: _"How do I merge a changeset from one branch to another?"_ - well, you could just use [`tf merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops) - _"You can use the merge command of the tf command-line utility to apply changes in an existing source branch to an existing target branch. You can merge an individual revision or a complete changeset to the target branch."_ - for example _"The following example merges changeset 137 into branch2."_ `c:\projects>tf merge /version:C137~C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive`

Comment: Thanks but I was really hoping to use the objects if possible. I may end up having to do that but it will be a last resort.